# Add ApplicationListener to Spring Boot during test

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing

We have a Spring Boot application. For correct startup we have implemented some logic into an `ApplicationListener`.

```
public class StartUpLogic implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent> {
  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent event) {
    // important logic
  }
}
```

In our `main` method we add this listener programatically:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(OurApplication.class);
  application.addListeners(new StartUpLogic());
  application.run();
}
```

Everything works fine in 'production'.

When we try to start our integration tests we're not sure how to add this listener.

Our test looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = [OurApplication::class], webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
public class OneIntegrationTest{
  // How to add our StartUpLogic() as listener?
}
```

So the question is: How is it possible to add an `ApplicationListener` in a unit test?

Comment: What class is this `main` method in?

Comment: Is adding the listener through autowiring an option, or does it have to be programmatic? I would try slapping a `@Component` on the listener class and removing the code from `main`